# How can I get a xib file to show up inside of storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

Followed this tutorial https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

I cannot find a clear and up to date way as a UI designer to use XIB files and see them in storyboard.

I tried this tutorial but it no longer works and I'm unable to see why, comments mention that this will no longer work for new versions of xCode.

https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d

I'd expect that I can get a XIB file to show up in storyboard.